# Why not use varchar type for every field in a table?

Tags: javascript, mysql

If you are accessing a database via a GET request (assuming most queries to server db are performed with HTTP request) from client side JS and get in return a json string, why would it matter what types are in the database fields if the return is of string type? Like why bother selecting types for each field?

Comment: Database datatypes should be correct for the data being stored in the columns. For example a date in a VARCHAR is almost useless as it makes querying using date funtions more complex. They have nothing to do with what happens to the data once it leaves the database

Comment: Because the database doesn't care about who will work with the data and in what format they need it.

Comment: The field types has nothing to do with what is being returned. It has to do with how it is stored.

Comment: Just because a JSON string is a string, doesn't mean the values IN the json string are a string. For example, this is a json string: `"{\"key\": 3}"`, but the value 3 will come out as a number after you do `JSON.parse`

Comment: If you use `ORDER BY` using a numeric datatype will sort numbers correctly.

Comment: For the same reason you could use a byte to store 8 boolean values, but wouldn't. It's just simply impractical. How would you add two SQL varchars? Would you want to write a framework of functions that handle varchars as different data types? For example, if you have a date, how do you get the day after that date if it's a string?

Comment: @mplungjan fixed, I tried it immediately after typing it and realized my error. thanks!

Comment: or, to flip the comments around: if all you need is to retrieve some strings, maybe mysql is not the right tool to store your data

Comment: You can have a table with all VarChar columns, just don't ask it to sort by date :)

Comment: Devil's advocate, you could store dates is ISO 8601 format and it would remain sortable. Still, don't do that.

Comment: I don't know why people down-voted this question. What he suggested was a terrible idea, but he ***asked a question***, and a very valid one. He didn't say "you should only use VARCHAR". He asked "why *shouldn't* you only use VARCHAR?" -- I think this is a great question, and more people need to ask questions like this to better understand performance and data integrity concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple very valid reason to not use VARCHAR for everything:

1. If the returned value from your API is a JSON string, then ***not*** every value is a string type. JSON can contain numbers, as well: `{name: "Steven", age: 29}`
2. Before the API ever returns a JSON string, the database must perform a query and extract data to return. The faster it can do this, the faster your application will be. VARCHAR fields are very slow to filter on because the actual data of the field is stored on a separate disk page and the record contains a pointer to it. Therefore filtering by name on a `CHAR(50)` field will be faster than filtering by name on a `VARCHAR` field
3. When joining tables, the slow filtering issue described above is even more prominent. Suppose you have two tables like `Users` and `Posts`, and the `Posts` table had a `user_id` field. If that ID were a VARCHAR then joining these tables would be ***much*** slower than if it were an integer
4. A VARCHAR field can contain invalid data. A person's age should only ever be a number. But if you had a VARCHAR field then you could put someone's age as "bob" into the database. What does that even mean? Now you have to start checking for bad data on the front end and you have to figure out how to handle it when it happens
5. VARCHAR fields are sorted one character at a time. This means that `"23"` comes before `"3"` (alphabetically) even though you would expect `3` to come before `23` (numerically). Try storing age as a VARCHAR and then saying `SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY age`
6. VARCHAR fields take up more space on disk than numerical fields. An integer can be stored in 32 bits (4 bytes). However a VARCHAR requires 1-4 bytes for the length, 4-8 bytes for a pointer to where the data is stored, plus one byte per character for the actual data. This means the number `1000000` is 4 bytes for an INTEGER but up to 19 bytes for a VARCHAR
7. SQL math operations will not work on VARCHAR fields. With numerical fields you can do things like `SELECT MAX(age) FROM Users` or `SELECT AVERAGE(age) FROM Users` or even `SELECT (age / 2) FROM Users`. None of these will work with a VARCHAR
8. This whole time I've been comparing VARCHAR to numerical fields, but SQL also provides DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP fields all of which have their own convenience methods or logic. You can subtract two DATE fields to get the number of days difference. This won't work if the dates are stored as VARCHARs
9. Numerical fields can be sub-divided into integer fields (which do not accept a decimal point) and floating point fields (which do accept a decimal point). This can be important when storing things like how many bedrooms a house has (will always be an integer. What does it mean to have "half a bedroom"?) versus storing things like square footage (which could reasonably be fractional if a room is something like 11.5' by 13.5')
10. Aggregation can be done on numerical fields (`SELECT SUM(income) FROM Workers`) but not on VARCHAR fields

I'm sure others will come up with more valid reasons, but the above should be sufficient to realize that VARCHAR is not the answer to everything.

Comment: Sorry - I deleted my comment suggesting that space was a good reason too. I don't mean to make your comment appear to be out of context.

Comment: @BillKarwin Comment tag :P The StackOverflow version of phone tag

Comment: Point 2 is not completly correct.. As Char datatype can also be stored off page in InnoDB https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html -> InnoDB encodes fixed-length fields greater than or equal to 768 bytes in length as variable-length fields, which can be stored off-page. For example, a CHAR(255) column can exceed 768 bytes